# Can't start postgres due to bad ALTER SYSTEM settings

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 at ubuntu 16.04. Today i tried to change few values in settings. Through pgAdmin query tool i've added the usage of non existing library:

```
 shared_preload_libraries = 'online_analyze, plantuner'
```

now postgres can't start due to the absence of that library and i can't rollback this setting, because i can't access psql or query tool in pgAdmin (postgres not started).

What can i do?

Comment: it resides on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html

> `ALTER SYSTEM` writes the given parameter setting to the
>   **postgresql.auto.conf** file, which is read in addition to
>   postgresql.conf

(formatting mine)

thus you can go ssh to the server and manually edit the file to let postgres to start.

you can easily locate it with `sudo find / -name postgresql.auto.conf`

Comment: i don't have this file... do i need to create it?

Comment: it is created when you run ALTER SYSTEM first time - look server side in `$PGDATA` or for some linux distros, `/etc/postgres*/*/`, you can easily locate it with `sudo find / -name postgresql.auto.conf`

Comment: i've found it in /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.auto.conf, thx a lot!

Comment: no worries. try removing the failing line and if it helps, please upvote and most important accept the answer - it might help other people and will give me a modest bonus

Comment: Mine was located here on OpenSUSE 15: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf`. Also, thank you, this was exactly what I needed.